# Any way to run byebug under passenger + nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, byebug

I developed a simple rails app which works in development environment under WEBrick. However, when I move to production environment it doesn't work. I fixed trivial errors relating to assets and things. However, some things just don't work. It would be extremely helpful to be able to see what is going on interactively with debugger.

I can insert `byebug` in the code, and it pauses code from running, but since neither *passenger* nor *nginx* logs to STDOUT (by default) I can't get to the byebug prompt. (and neither read STDIN)

Is there a way to run `byebug` under *passenger + nginx*?

**Edit**

This time my issue [was related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35195652/788700) to https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passenger author here. Byebug integration is available in Passenger Enterprise: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/debugging_console/ruby/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/davejamesmiller/ruby-debug-passenger
This adds a rake task, just run 'rake debug' and you'll be connected to your code at the point where it hits byebug

Comment: This crashes on Ruby 2.2+, not maintained anymore.

Comment: Anything more on this? How do I debug a ruby app on passenger  running as an apache module?