# Confirmation token mentioned twice in GET request, but only once in the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx, devise, passenger

I'm facing a strange bug when I follow confirmation link from devise email. The link is correct:

```
.../ru/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=yDNePwDTbxBzy5PqZE1e
```

However in server log I get:

```
Started GET "/ru/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=yDNePwDTbxBzy5PqZE1e?confirmation_token=yDNePwDTbxBzy5PqZE1e"
```

As you see it is mentioned twice. For this reason I can't confirm the email.

The strangest thing is that it works in webrick, and I only see this issue in production (which happen to be nginx + passenger).

It might be the problem with my setup. I'm using Rails v4, and Devise v3. I re-wrote default devise confirmation#edit controller, and a couple of others, since I wanted to implement "sign-up by email" strategy, and also use ldap_authenticatable model instead of database_authenticatable. I also patched ldap_authenticatable to support multiple LDAPs. But even so -- can you point me where I should look to dig into my issue?

**Edit**

Middleware: production environment is 4 entries shorter:

- production

  ```
    $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake middleware 
    use Rack::Sendfile 
    use Rack::Lock 
    use Rack::Runtime 
    use Rack::MethodOverride 
    use ActionDispatch::RequestId 
    use Rails::Rack::Logger 
    use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions 
    use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions 
    use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp 
    use ActionDispatch::Callbacks 
    use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement 
    use ActiveRecord::QueryCache 
    use ActionDispatch::Cookies 
    use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore 
    use ActionDispatch::Flash
    use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
    use Rack::Head
    use Rack::ConditionalGet
    use Rack::ETag
    use Warden::Manager
    run Login::Application.routes
  ```
- development:

  ```
    $ RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake middleware
    use Rack::Sendfile
  + use ActionDispatch::Static
    use Rack::Lock
    use Rack::Runtime
    use Rack::MethodOverride
    use ActionDispatch::RequestId
    use Rails::Rack::Logger
    use ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions
  + use WebConsole::Middleware
    use ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions
    use ActionDispatch::RemoteIp
  + use ActionDispatch::Reloader
    use ActionDispatch::Callbacks
  + use ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending
    use ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement
    use ActiveRecord::QueryCache
    use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
    use ActionDispatch::Flash
    use ActionDispatch::ParamsParser
    use Rack::Head
    use Rack::ConditionalGet
    use Rack::ETag
    use Warden::Manager
    run Login::Application.routes
  ```

**Edit 2**

I found out what was the reason: the link in the email was http. If I change that to https -- it works. So one just have to add

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:protocol => 'https'}
```

in `config/environments/production.rb` and it works (on web-server restart). [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5760867/788700)

Comment: Could the link itself be malformed? Have you overrided the mailer view?

Comment: @max: I only added localization to the email. As far as I can see the link in the email I get from devise is correct. However I overrided the confirmation view. I store confirmation token in the hidden field tag in order to pass it to the post request. In my confirmation view user picks a password, and if @user.error.empty? I find the user by the token I get from the hidden field and update him in the ldap.

Comment: The only thing which is really relevant here is the view which creates the email body and or the helper method that creates the confirmation URL. Whatever client you're opening it up with obviously does not like the link at all since it interprets it as a malformed URL. URLs are not supposed to have more the one query delimiter `?`. Remember here that the request URL is printed to the log long before the request hits your rails controllers so any devise overrides have not been started. Its pretty unlikely that you have been able to fudge the middleware up to rewrite the request URL either.

Comment: @max: looks like it is someone in the middle: I just tried to visit `http://my.site.ru/ru/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=test` and I got `Started GET "/ru/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=test?confirmation_token=test"` in the server logs. This proves that the link in the email is correct.

Comment: Thats very strange. You can use `rake middleware` to get a list of the middleware in your stack.